# Get components of a graph (SCC)

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am new at algorithm. I am confused about this following graph. I am finding the strongly connected components of the below graph.

[GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wypA.png)

If I am not wrong, the connection should be: A > D > E > C > B > F

Can anyone make sure about that? Or correct me if I am wrong?

And how can I describe / draw that solution? Any idea about this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component), strongly connected components are a partition of the graph  into subgraphs such that, within every subgraph, every node is reachable from every node. We can simply apply that definition to your graph to see that

- B is a component by itself, because it has no incoming edges.
- G is a component by itself, because it has no outgoing edges.
- C is a component by itself, because its only outgoing edge is to G.
- A, D, E, F is a component. Every node is reachable from every node because they form a cycle.